# Error using Minted for syntax highlighting in custom document class

Tags: errors, pdftex, color, document-classes, minted

I am writing Master thesis in LaTeX and want to use [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) package for source code syntax highlighting. I have installed it successfully and minimal example from `minted` documentation works just fine.

The problem is when I use document class predefined at Prague Technical University called `FITthesis`. I believe it is a `Fitthesis.cls` file (attached).

After command `pdflatex -shell-escape MintedTest` I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color 
                                                  }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.8 \begin{document}
```

This is minimal example:

```
\documentclass[thesis=M,english]{FITthesis}[2012/10/20]

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas what to do? I am LaTeX newbie. I didn't even find the file where this error is.

- Link to log file and `Fitthesis.cls` file: http://cl.ly/OGSm

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try adding `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. Same error. :-/

Comment: it is a problem with your document class. With the standard class `article` you won't get an error

Comment: The error happens when LaTeX is processing `\begin{document}` and has nothing to do with `minted`.

Comment: When I remove Minted everything works fine.

Comment: I have discovered that `\usepackage{color}` triggers the same error. Any ideas please?

Comment: `minted` loads `xcolor`, so it may be a conflict between the two color packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This runs without the internal color error, just errors about not supplying keywords and other data.

```
\documentclass[thesis=M,english]{FITthesis}[2012/10/20]

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\color{black}
\let\default@color\current@color
\makeatother

\department{ddd}
\title{ttt}
\supervisor{sss}
\author{aaa}
\authorFN{aaa}
\authorGN{aaa}

\begin{document}

aaa

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert **\RequirePackage{color}** before **\AtBeginDocument{ ... }**

in the class **FITthesis.cls** it will work as well ;-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).